# When posting a form from Site A to Site B, does the POST request include Site B's cookie?

Tags: html, forms, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

It's basically an OAuth2/OIDC (IdentityServer4) problem happening when the user's browser loads Identity Service (Site A) page that FORM POSTs `authorization code` and `id_token` back to the relying party site (Site B).

The relying party site (Site B) receives the FORM POST request but it doesn't have the cookies of Site B it previously placed on the user's browser, which makes the verification process failing.

I have tried to set ALLOW-CROSS-ORIGIN-ACCESS header but it didn't seem to help with the FORM POST scenario (not ajax call).

In the common application of OAuth2/OIDC integration, should I not expect cookies being posted back to the relying part site (Site B) along with the `authorization code` & `id_token`? Or more commonly describing it, when FORM POSTing from Site A to Site B, should I not expect any cookies of Site B will be part of the request to Site B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not CORS, that's another issue, most likely related to Same Site Cookie Policy. And that's very browser specific.

When your Site B is ASP.NET core you can either set:

```cs
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(opts=>{opts.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;});
//and
app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions{MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None});
```

(see longer discussion [on ASP.NET Core github](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4647))

or use more intelligent and secure [trick](https://brockallen.com/2019/01/11/same-site-cookies-asp-net-core-and-external-authentication-providers/) with switching *other site* to *same site* POST, offered by Identity Server author.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, d_f. I'm a bit reluctant to blindly set Same Site Cookie Policy to None because it leaves the site more vulnerable to CSRF. Fortunately, the solution I took works in a different flow (authorize code flow) without requiring cookies for Site B. So I'd keep the Same Site Cookie Policy as it is and work around. The question in this post has been fully addressed though.

Comment: Glad that you solved it. And the solution is really good: nowadays hybrid flow becomes... not really deprecated, but not the recommended one, and the code flow is aimed to replace it.